# Subscribe to multiple topics simultaneously

Tags: ros, openni, subscribe

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I implement a stair detection algorithmus for ROS. Therefore the node analyzes input data from an Asus Xtion camera via openni_launch. Can the node subscribe to both topics, /camera/depth/image and /camera/rgb/image, and receive both image frames to the same time?

Thanks in advance,
Max

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221617/subscribe-to-multiple-topics-simultaneously/) by [ne0h](https://answers.ros.org/users/25083/ne0h/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-11-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at this: http://answers.ros.org/question/9705/synchronizer-and-image_transportsubscriber/

---

Originally posted by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) with karma: 1642 on 2015-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ne0h](https://answers.ros.org/users/25083/ne0h/) on 2015-11-28**:
Looks good, thank you. I will take a closer look next week.

**Comment by [ne0h](https://answers.ros.org/users/25083/ne0h/) on 2015-12-03**:
Thanks, I used an ApproximateTimeSynchronizer (http://docs.ros.org/api/message_filters/html/python/#message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer)